# Open PDF In PDF Viewer

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf

I have a PDF in the assets folder: `assets/my_resume.pdf`.

How can I open it in a PDF viewer? I don't want to open it in a widget. I want it to open outside of my app with whatever PDF viewer is available to this device.

I tried: https://pub.dev/packages/open_file but that doesn't work with assets.

```
Future<void> launchPdf() async {

}
```

How can I do this? I mostly care about mobile so not even considering web.

Comment: What do you mean by "not wanting to open it in a widget"? There are packages out there that will open the pdf inside your app and create a full-screen reading experience as expected. But they are still constructed as a widget

Comment: I want it to open outside of my app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best method, but you could load the pdf file data, and save it to, for example, the Document directory on the device, and after that, use the open file package to open the pdf with a native device app.

```dart
void openAsset() async {
    // load pdf into ram
    ByteData pdf = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).load('assets/your_pdf.pdf');
    // get documents directory
    Directory documents = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    // write data to a file in the documents directory
    await File(documents.path + '/your_pdf.pdf').writeAsBytes(pdf.buffer.asUint8List());
    // call open_pdf function
    // ...
}
```

(Didn't test the code)